# Filter get-eventlog by the subjects account name

Tags: powershell, events, event-log, get-eventlog

I've created a little script that runs on our districts domain controllers that sends out an email any time a user is created in AD to our networking team. The script works great, but we want to filter out our MIM system that creates new users every morning based on new student intake and newly hired employees. Here is an example of the event that triggers when our MIM system creates a user.

A user account was created.

Subject:

```
Security ID:        NSD\srvMIMADMA

Account Name:       srvMIMADMA

Account Domain:     NSD

Logon ID:       0x564EF2A6
```

New Account:

```
Security ID:        NSD\student

Account Name:       student

Account Domain:     NSD
```

Attributes:

```
SAM Account Name:   student

Display Name:       name, student

User Principal Name:    student@email.com

Home Directory:     -

Home Drive:     -

Script Path:        -

Profile Path:       -

User Workstations:  -

Password Last Set:  <never>

Account Expires:        <never>

Primary Group ID:   513

Allowed To Delegate To: -

Old UAC Value:      0x0

New UAC Value:      0x11

User Account Control:   

    Account Disabled

    'Normal Account' - Enabled

User Parameters:    -

SID History:        -

Logon Hours:        <value not set>
```

Additional Information:

```
Privileges      -
```

Here is the script I am using.

```
#---Generate email on new ADS account creation---#

$event = get-eventlog -LogName Security -InstanceId "4720" -Newest 1
$EmailBody = $event.Message

if ($event.EntryType -eq "Success" -and $event.UserName -ne "NSD\srvMIMADMA" -and $event.EventID -eq "4720")
{
    $mail = @{
            from        = "DomainController@email.org"
            to          = "me@email.org"
            cc          = @("coworker1@email.org", "coworker2@email.org")
            subject     = "New AD user was created"
            smtpserver  = "10.10.10.10"
            port        = "PORT"
            body        = $EmailBody
            }
    
    Write-host "Sending Email"
    
    Send-MailMessage @mail
}
else
{
    write-host "No error found"
    write-host "Here is the log entry that was inspected:"
    $event
}
```

I was attempting to use `event.UserName` to filter out our MIM system, but that looks like its not working because our team got an email for it this morning. Is there a way to filter out events generated by a specific user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$event.Message -like "*NSD\srvMIMADMA*"
```

or

```
$event.Message -notlike "*NSD\srvMIMADMA*"
```

instead of

```
$event.UserName -ne "NSD\srvMIMADMA"
```

Comment: This worked really well! Thanks for that. I found a little bit of trouble adding the NSD\ at the front, but removing that solved it.
Thanks!